# Verify if all target nodes are reachable from at least one source node in Python NetworkX

Tags: python, routes, networkx, dijkstra

I'm wondering what the most efficient method would be to verify that all target nodes from a set T are reachable from at least one source node S in Python's NetworkX library.

To me, it should be a simple many-to-many Dijkstra function call, where S is the source node list input and T is the target node list input. I could then verify that the returned value indicates that at least one of the routings was a success. This is how I would approach the problem using PostgreSQL's pgRouting extension, for those that may be familiar with that:

```
pgr_dijkstra(edges_sql, start_vids, end_vids)
```

However, [it seems from the documentation that a function where both the sources and targets are lists does not exist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html). The closest I could find is `multi_source_dijkstra` or `all_pairs_dijkstra`.

I feel that `multi_source_dijkstra` is insufficient because I cannot specify a list of multiple target nodes as input, and that `all_pairs_dijkstra` is too much because I don't want to waste time testing connectivity between source nodes or between target nodes. Furthermore, I am fully expecting my graph to have gaps within itself, and I just want to test the original condition - that all target nodes are just reachable from at least one source node.

I'm sure that something can be cobbled together the `multi_source_dijkstra` function, but I want to this be as efficient as possible so I am hoping that I am just missing an obvious implementation that would do what I want most efficiently.

EDIT: Image for @abc. The red/yellow, red/pink lines and green lines represent a subgraph which I am using in the DFS or BFS algorithm. This configuration is returning True, claiming that all the red dots (targets) are reachable from the green dot (source).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using a shortest path algorithm such as *Dijkstra*'s one?
If your goal is to check whether all target nodes are reachable from at least one source node you only need a graph traversal algorithm (e.g., [bfs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree) and [dfs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree)).

```
S = {1,2}
T = {3,4}
g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(6, 0.3, directed=True)

# True if all the nodes of T are reachable from at least a node in S
any(T < set(nx.bfs_tree(g,s).nodes()) for s in S)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see what you mean about Dijkstra being overkill. I understand what you are going here, saying that if the target nodes are a subsbet of the nodes in the BFS or the DFS tree (which originates from source nodes) then it means that the targets are connected. However it seems to be returning true when only one target node is connected, see the image I put in the original post.

Comment: Sorry, scratch that, I had actually just specified my sources and targets backwards. D'oh! It works perfectly now, thanks for your response.

Comment: I assumed the graph to be directed. If as in the image you added the graph is undirected then a single visit from a random target node is enough. If in the visit you meet all the target nodes and at least a source node, than the answer is true, false otherwise.

Comment: I understand what you mean but my graph may in fact be composed of two non-connected parts, each of which will have at least one source node, so I think I do have to iterate through and check each